# How to use interchangeably virtuabox vm with vmplayer vm?

Tags: virtualbox, vmware-player

So basically being able to turn on the same vm on any. One at a time, without having to create a vm for each one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same machine back and forth is not possible.

You must convert the machines. Player uses the same format as Workstation.

[Convert between VBox and VMware](https://www.howtogeek.com/125640/how-to-convert-virtual-machines-between-virtualbox-and-vmware/)

> Migrating to another virtual machine program can be intimidating. if
> you already have your virtual machines set up they way you like them,
> you don’t necessarily have to install them from scratch – you can
> **migrate your existing virtual machines.**
>
> VirtualBox and VMware use different virtual machine formats, but each
> supports the standard Open Virtualization Format. Convert your
> existing virtual machine to OVF or OVA and you’ll be able to import it
> into another virtual machine program.
>
> Unfortunately, this may not always work perfectly, as VirtualBox and
> VMware both seem to use slightly different OVA/OVF implementations
> that aren’t entirely compatible. If this doesn’t work, you may want to
> reinstall your virtual machine’s guest operating system from scratch.
>
> VirtualBox to VMware Before migrating a virtual machine from
> VirtualBox to VMware, ensure it’s “powered off” in VirtualBox – not
> suspended. If it’s suspended, launch the virtual machine and shut it
> down.
>
> VirtualBox will create a nOpen Virtualization Format Archive (OVA
> file) that VMware can import. This may take some time, depending on
> the size of your virtual machine’s disk file.
>
> To import the OVA file in VMware, click the Open a Virtual Machine
> option and browse to your OVA file.